# docker serivce starts every hour though it is disabled

Tags: centos, docker

Though the docker.service is disabled, it is starting every hour, at the top of each hour. I stop it and for unknown reason it starts again at the top of next hour....
I don't find any crontabs which could trigger it.

Example of this issue caught on my system:

```
[root@c2 ~]# while true;do date;ps -ef|grep docke[r];sleep 5;done
Sun Dec  1 16:59:45 UTC 2019
Sun Dec  1 16:59:50 UTC 2019
Sun Dec  1 16:59:55 UTC 2019
Sun Dec  1 17:00:00 UTC 2019
Sun Dec  1 17:00:05 UTC 2019
root      8930     1  4 17:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --init-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json --selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false --storage-driver overlay2
root      8935  8930  0 17:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker-containerd-current -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc --runtime-args --systemd-cgroup=true
Sun Dec  1 17:00:10 UTC 2019
root      8930     1  2 17:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current --init-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json --selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false --storage-driver overlay2
root      8935  8930  0 17:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker-containerd-current -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --shim docker-containerd-shim --runtime docker-runc --runtime-args --systemd-cgroup=true
^C
```

And docker service status:

```
[root@c2 spool]# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-12-01 17:00:03 UTC; 4min 31s ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 8930 (dockerd-current)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─8930 /usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/lib...
           └─8935 /usr/bin/docker-containerd-current -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `docker` service as installed by the `docker-ce` package is controlled by two unit files:

```
[root@docker system]# rpm -ql docker-ce | grep /lib/systemd/system
/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
```

Regardless of whether or not the *service* is running, it can be activated by a connection to the socket: that is, any time you (or a cron job, or someone else) runs the `docker` command, if the `docker` service isn't already running it will be started in order to service the connection.

To completely disable Docker you will need to:

```
systemctl disable --now docker.service docker.socket
```

Using `disable --now` will (a) stop the service and socket units and (b) prevent them from restarting when your host reboots.

Answer (score -1):

The docker service is no longer starting every hour, when I stopped (and disabled) `docker-cleanup.timer` service too (I found it was running on "systemctl|grep docker" output):

```
  docker-cleanup.timer         loaded active waiting   Run docker-cleanup every hour
```

When I start docker on centos, docker-cleanup.timer is started again, and is not stopped when I stop docker with "systemctl stop docker". It is causing that at next hour docker engine is started again automatically.